# Load referenced item in context language with Glass Mapper

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a multi-language website running Sitecore 8.1 and using Glass Mapper 4.2.1. The content is translated in all needed languages, but the configuration item exist only in English.

When I now have the Sitecore.Context.Language to German and load a configuration item, Glass Mapper is loading this in English. That's ok and wished, as this item is not existing in German. Within this configuration item I have a property to a referenced item that exists in English, German and French. Unfortunately Glass Mapper now loads this item in English, as the configuration item is loaded in English instead of using the Sitecore.Context.Language. Is there a possibility to load the referenced item directly in the Sitecore.Context.Language?

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: can you please provide the glass model class that you are using?

Comment: It's a Sitecore reference field for that Glass Mapper uses the SitecoreFieldTypeMapper (see https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/DataMappers/SitecoreFieldTypeMapper.cs). The problem for me is on line 57 I believe. There it uses the item.language instead of the Sitecore.Context.Language.

Answer (score 2):

To me this makes sense as a default behavior for Glass (as seen [here](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/DataMappers/SitecoreFieldTypeMapper.cs))... if an item is loaded in a language, traversing other content off that item should be in the same language.

This is why [Glass Maps and delegates](https://cardinalcore.co.uk/2014/08/06/glass-mapper-introducing-glass-maps/) are great, imho, because you can easily override these behaviors or otherwise introduce your own mapping logic.
For example, assuming that `Config` is your configuration (in English) and `ConfigReference` is the type you want to retrieve from the `Config Reference` field (in the context language):

`public class ConfigGlassMap : SitecoreGlassMap<Config>
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Map(config =>
            {
                config.Delegate(x => x.ConfigReference).GetValue(context =>
                    context.Service.GetItem<ConfigReference>(Guid.Parse(context.Item["Config Reference"]), Sitecore.Context.Language));
            });
        }
    }`